# Unable to load a previously dumped pickle file of large size in Python

Tags: python, numpy, networkx, pickle

I used cPickle and protocol version 2 to dump some computation results.  The code looks like this:

```
> f = open('foo.pck', 'w')
> cPickle.dump(var, f, protocol=2)
> f.close()
```

The variable var is a tuple of length two.  The type of var[0] is a list and var[1] is a numpy.ndarray.

The above code segment successfully generated a file with large size (~1.7G).

However, when I tried to load the variable from foo.pck, I got the following error.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/user_account/tmp/<ipython-input-3-fd3ecce18dcd> in <module>()
----> 1 v = cPickle.load(f)
ValueError: buffer size does not match array size
```

The loading codes looks like the following.

```
> f= open('foo.pck', 'r')
> v = cPickle.load(f)
```

I also tried to use pickle (instead of cPickle) to load the variable, but got a similar error msg as follows.

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/user_account/tmp/<ipython-input-3-aa6586c8e4bf> in <module>()
----> 1 v = pickle.load(f)

/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.pyc in load(file)
   1368 
   1369 def load(file):
-> 1370     return Unpickler(file).load()
   1371 
   1372 def loads(str):

/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.pyc in load(self)
    856             while 1:
    857                 key = read(1)
--> 858                 dispatch[key](self)
    859         except _Stop, stopinst:
    860             return stopinst.value

/usr/lib64/python2.6/pickle.pyc in load_build(self)
   1215         setstate = getattr(inst, "__setstate__", None)
   1216         if setstate:
-> 1217             setstate(state)
   1218             return
   1219         slotstate = None

ValueError: buffer size does not match array size
```

I tried the same code segments to a much smaller size data and it worked fine.  So my best guess is that I reached the loading size limitation of pickle (or cPickle).  However, it is strange to dump successfully (with large size variable) but failed to load.

If this is indeed a loading size limitation problem, how should I bypass it? If not, what can be the possible cause of the problem?

Any suggestion is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried opening the files in binary mode (`wb` and `rb`)? I don't see it in the docs though, maybe it's only important for Python 3.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  I'm using Python 2.6.
I checked the dumped pickle file.  It is a binary file.
I tried to open the file by open(filename, 'rb') and then load the data, but unfortunately I got the same error message. :-(

I also tried the code in both python and ipython.

Comment: You should have created the file with 'wb'. You might have to convert line endings in the binary file to get it to open.

Comment: I'll try to modify the dumping code from 'w' to 'wb'.  But I feel like this might not be the reason since a smaller dumped file works well.

As for the line ending conversion, from the article here http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node73.html I'm assuming the line endings for text file and binary file are the same in Linux?

Comment: Some questions : does it happen systematically/often/once in a while? Was numpy updated between the creation of the pickle and its reload? What's the numpy version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about save & load the numpy array by `numpy.save()` & `np.load()`?

You can save the pickled list and the numpy array to the same file:

```
import numpy as np
import cPickle
data = np.random.rand(50000000)
f = open('foo.pck', 'wb')
cPickle.dump([1,2,3], f, protocol=2)
np.save(f, data)
f.close()
```

to read the data:

```
import cPickle
import numpy as np
f= open('foo.pck', 'rb')
v = cPickle.load(f)
data = np.load(f)
print data.shape, data
```

Comment: Can you please explain why this works? I am using an another lib (pandas) which is failing in case of large pkl files.